# How to sort over two columns with exponents in bash

Tags: bash, sorting, double

I need to sort some data from file "test" (example of data):

```
1.03073 0.000193333 2.02417 2.15578
1.03073 0.0002 2.12005 2.14534
1.03073 1.33333e-05 100 0
1.03073 2e-05 100 0
```

so that it is sorted over first column first, and over second afterwards.
I tried with

```
sort -n -k1 -k2 -u test >test1
```

but it messes up because he does not see "e-5" part.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `-g`:

```
sort -k1,2 -g file
```

From `man sort`:

> **-g, --general-numeric-sort**
>
> compare according to general numerical value

#### Test

```
$ cat a
1.03073 0.000193333 2.02417 2.15578
1.03073 0.0002 2.12005 2.14534
1.03073 1.33333e-05 100 0
1.03073 2e-05 100 0
1.03073 2e-04 100 0
1.03073 2e-06 100 0

$ sort -k1,2 -g a
1.03073 0.000193333 2.02417 2.15578
1.03073 0.0002 2.12005 2.14534
1.03073 1.33333e-05 100 0
1.03073 2e-04 100 0
1.03073 2e-05 100 0
1.03073 2e-06 100 0
```

Comment: +1 I knew about `g` but didn't know if that supports `"e-5"` part also.